# What version of .NET am I running?

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, version

In Windows 7, how do I tell what version of the .NET framework I have installed?

In previous operating systems, (i.e. Vista/XP), I was able to go to Add/Remove Programs and it'd show all the versions of .NET Framework installed. With Windows 7, I just see "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile" (in the Programs and Features control panel).

My guess is that it is only showing the latest/largest version number for my .NET framework install?

Note: I did also check Programs and Features > Installed Updates, to see if all installed .NET framework versions were shown there, but no luck.

Comment: The reason Windows 7 isn't showing you any of the others is because it comes with versions 3.5 and below pre-installed.

Comment: I am running Windows 10 and in February 2021 the answers below have allowed me to find all my installed versions. I can probably not edit tags, but someone might want to add Windows 10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look in `<%WINDIR%>\Microsoft.NET\Framework` (and/or `Framework64`), this will give you fairly reliable hint.

It may contain multiple version directories such as `v4.0.30319` and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has a knowledge base article that answers this question:

[How to determine which versions and service pack levels of the Microsoft .NET Framework are installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318785)

The article lists registry keys to check to determine if a particular .NET Framework version is installed.

Windows 7 shipped with the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 included as an operating system component, so it does not show up in the main Programs and Features window.  You may be able to see portions of it in the *Turn Windows Features On or Off* section of Programs and Features.  The Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 includes .NET 2.0 SP2 and .NET 3.0 SP2.

Comment: That link only gives instructions up to and including .NET 4.6.x.  For .NET 4.7 see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed).

Answer (score 2):

.NET V3.5 is installed as part of the OS in Windows 7 and you cannot uninstall it I don't think, so this is why it does not show up in Add/Remove.

By default this aslo means you have V2.0 and V3.0 as they all share a common CLR (V2.0).

Answer (score 1):

.NET CLR Versions (V1.0, 1.1, 2 and 4) will install side by side—you could have *all* of them.

3 and 3.5 were additional libraries added to the V2 runtime.